# How can i detect the current link of page through php or java script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla

actually i created a website in joomla,
 & in Facebook Page i give the link of that website page in iframe.

I made an individual menu in joomla in which i applied different template & use that menu link in iframe on Facebook.

The thing is in that page(face book page) if the user click on the any link which refer to the dynamic pages of the website, so its open that in the default website template, for this i used another technique i passed token with the url & start the session with that template
like

> www.mywesite.com?facebook=1

but the problem comes it stores the session until unless new token is passed to destroy facebook session like this

> www.mywesite.com?facebook=0

**Now I am thinking that to detect the window if the url calls from iframe then i pass token facebook=1 & if the url calls normally from the window then it pass facebook=0.

i am thinking some thinking like this

if(window != top) {document.write("1");}

Please give me an idea how to do this through php or java script what ever.
**

Comment: Please write shorter sentences. I don't understand your 3rd paragraph after reading it twice.

Comment: Christopher Marshall how can i accept can you guide me please

Answer (score 1):

Or with javascript: [document.URL](http://javascript.gakaa.com/document-url.aspx)

`document.URL`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current URL in PHP with:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Read more about [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

**Aside:** You should contribute back to the StackOverflow community by accepting answers. This not only awards points to other users but also yourself. Furthermore, you'll be less likely to receive such comments regarding your accept rate.

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: yeah but that returns the URI of the page within the iframe

so it doesnot work

Comment: You need to be mindful where you use the code, depending on if you want the page or the iFrames URI.

Comment: you mean i place that script in my website so in the when it request through fb iframe it detects that, the rquest comes from Fb iframe..???